# Why was my request to review my website voted off-topic?

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question about my Code Review Stack Exchange post: [Website for demonstrating company skillset](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/166608/website-for-demonstrating-company-skillset)

The question above was voted off-topic when the only error that I get on my browser console is the map key error. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: I think your question got closed by a misunderstanding over whether the code in it is broken or not. To my understanding it's not broken, but it may appear that way for users who try to copy-paste it but without using a valid API key. I reopened it now.

Comment: Thanks @janos for your help.

Answer (score 6):

I first saw this question at around [revision 13](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/166608/13), it had a working stack snippet, but when you ran it you'd get two error messages.

> Error: {
>     "message": "uncaught exception: InvalidValueError: myMap is not a function",
>     "filename": "",
>     "lineno": 0,
>     "colno": 0
>   }

> Error: Google Maps API error: InvalidKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#invalid-key-map-error

When I saw these I instinctively went to vote to close the question, what made matters worse was that the errors took up the entire stack snippet. I however enlarged the stack snippet so I could see what else was there and a fully working website was there.

There were comments saying that the code is broken, which were getting upvotes. I don't know if you commented to say it was working. But you should have adjusted your question to mention that the two 'errors' were due to a bad API key, and not required for the website to work. So other users coming to the question can clearly see that it is working as intended.

[EBrown later commented](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/166608#comment317458_166608) saying it's not broken, since it was the tenth, plus, comment on the question, you'd have to scroll a while to see it. Which significantly reduces it's impact. So I upvoted the comment, and left.

---

> Why is my question voted off-topic?

It was because people mistakenly took the above two errors to mean your website didn't work.

If something like this happens again, update your question so that you *clearly state* that the code works. In this case adding "Currently the provided code has two errors due to an intentionally incorrect API key. The code otherwise works as intended." as a paragraph would have been enough.

Comment: As one of the people who voted to close this question, I agree with this answer.

Comment: Very nicely explained, thanks

Comment: thanks @Peilonrayz for explaining.

Comment: Thanks for explaining these things and I am not blaming you but I had to find a solution that is why I posted this question here.I completely understand what you are saying but I would like to say this before voting the question of a new user off-topic please do confirm whether the question is really off-topic because I think 5 other users voted that off-topic only @EBrown checked that well.